# Setting button mnemonic key events without having to use ALT

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, key-bindings

Is there a way to set a button key event in Java so that <kbd>Alt</kbd> does not have to be pressed. For example, when this is used `setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)` it is required for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> to be pressed in the application. How can I get around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would take a look at the [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) tutorial. You can specify any `KeyStroke` to perform any `Action`.

Answer (score -1):

Create a KeyListener, or extend a KeyAdapter. Like this:

```
private class MnemonicWorkaround extends KeyAdapter{

     @Override
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int c = e.getKeyCode();
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
         // do something.
        }
      }
  }
```

Then add it using `component.addKeyListener(new MnemonicWorkaround());`

Comment: Just be wary of which component to add the listener to, and whether it has / maintains focus.

Comment: -1 for keyListener, it's useless here (as it is nearly always)

Comment: Why is it nearly always useless?

Comment: because they are so low-level that they can't do what is required ;-) The general rule is to go for the highest abstraction available (which are keybindings in this context)